# mongoose mongodb errno 10042

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Please help to get rid of this error:

I could connect to my mongodb when developing expressjs application without any problem before. Now after a couple of updates (nodejs, npm, bower...), I started to get an error I can't even find a notion of it on the google. This is the error message:

```
14 Jul 19:10:31 - [nodemon] restarting due to change
14 Jul 19:10:31 - [nodemon] starting `node api.js`
  api listening on port: 3000
  connection error: { [MongoError: connect Unknown sys
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect Unknown system errno 10042' }
```

and this is the code that hits to this error:

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var port = Number(3000);
  var UserSchema = '';
  var User = '';
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization')

  next();
  });

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pjwt4');
   var db = mongoose.connection;
   db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
   db.once('open', function (callback) {
    UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
    });
    User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
   });

   app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var user = req.body;
        var newUser = new User({
      email: user.email,
       password: user.password
    });
    newUser.save(function(err){
      res.status(200).json(newUser);
    });
    });

   app.listen(port, function(){
     console.log('api listening on port: ' + port);
    });
```

**Edit:**
I still have no answer to this, but I'm pretty sure that it is because of the updates to version of a module, why? because I have exactly the same project but with a different Package.json and when I do "npm insatll" then run that one, I get a warning from mongoose, saying that " This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose" but it runs and I don't get that error message! It connects to my mongodb while the latest version gives that error. Will be happy to have some help from you to understand it.

Comment: Are you sure mongo is running?

Comment: 100%, I'm not that much newbee with it, well and noway expert. Well as you see, I'm getting an err msg from MongoDb and it must be already running to send it!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:
in my Package.json I have:
"mongoose": "^4.0.7"
when I change it to:
"mongoose": "~3.8.8"
it installs and works fine.

It seems that the problem is due to some dependencies not getting installed and I can't understand why. If I try to install 4.0.0 or 4.0.8 I get to the same problem. I provide some of the error stack output (not formatted) just you can see these ERR! marks there. I hope this helps someone that gets the same problem. Sorry I couldn't figure out the problem fully!

```
...
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (i:\Documents
gs\AA\Desktop\tst\2\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\bson\node_modul
t\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (ch
s.js:823:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "node" "i:\\Documents and Settings\\AA\\Desk
2\\node_modules\\mongoose\\node_modules\\bson\\node_modules\\bson-ext\
les\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp.js" "install" "--fallback-to-buil
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd i:\Documents and Settings\AA\Desktop\tst\2\node_
ngoose\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
...
```

Comment: which version mongo and node are you running?

Comment: Yousef, please: mongodb: v3.0.4, node: v0.10.33

Comment: Yousef, thanks, I just downloaded msi (I'm in win32) and installed it. Now "node --version" output is v0.12.7.

Comment: are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I append my new code as Edit(2nd) in the main body for easier use. Thank you very much for supporting.